# Microsoft Azure and g-suite

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, google-workspace

I want to create a single-sign on between G-suite and Microsoft Azure.
Suppose I've a domain defined for my organization in my G-suite. I want my users to login to Microsoft Azure using Single-sign on from G-suite as Idp.
I've looked through few tutorials but not able to find out how this is done.

Comment: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/direct-federation.

Answer (score 1):

As per Allen's Link. please read through that. it has instructions on Direct Federation. Normally you would use direct federation more for partner businesses and not your own. since your org should have a azure ad Tenant / Domain . so your internal users should normally be in that tenant.

But because sometimes you don't want to for various reasons, you could in theory use B2B direct federation for your own users. 
As per the documentation though, please be aware, if you direct federate your users and set it all up in your azure tenant, and want to move that domain to azure ad later, there will be complications, you will likely have to delete all the guest users you added, and so on. so plan accordingly.

Comment: What I want to do exactly is... I want to create a multi cloud authentication from G-suite which means I want user to have a single credentials to have access to AWS,Azure and GCP using single sign on. I've figured out for AWS by using AWS SSO. GCP can also be done directly but not sure about azure and I'm having a hard time with it.

Comment: ok, well if that is your requirement, then yes, create is using a directly federated b2b as per the link allen provided. you still have to manually invite each "guest" gcloud user into your azure tenant and give them the appropriate / required permissions.

Comment: I am having doubts in how the attribute mapping part of SAML app at g-suite end is configured. Can you please help me in what type of attributes are to be mapped.

Comment: I would imagine per the specs, you set up the appropriate / required attributes in a custom app on the google idp side. https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en